# MySQL select that shows row with a specific value first

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT userid, name
FROM users 
WHERE nationality="US" 
ORDER BY name
```

Suppose I want a user with the `userid=101` and `nationality="US`" to be shown first no matter what, and it's really important to do it using one query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `FIELD`

```
SELECT userid, name FROM users WHERE nationality="US" ORDER BY FIELD(user_id,101) DESC, name asc
```

[Field Documentation](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/209784)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT userid, name, IF(user = 101, 1 , 2) AS rank 
    FROM users WHERE nationality = "US"
) AS subselect ORDER BY subselect.rank ASC, subselect.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do that:

```
SELECT userid, name, (userid=101) AS test FROM users WHERE nationality="US" ORDER BY test DESC, name ASC
```